# How to get specific content from a webpage using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to get the most recent publication's author and co-author names from google scholar page of an author. For this I am trying to use curl with php. But as the div has no specific ID for this and also has similar className for multiple div, I am unable to track data by web-scraping.
So far I tried this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>

// To Do:
// from $data variable need to get the author's name.
// <div class="gs_gray">R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz,...</div>
```

Comment: You may want to look at Xpath for getting data of the specific element in the HTML. https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse the html with DOMDocument and DOMXPath, you can iterate the articles with the XPath

```
//*[@id="gsc_a_b"]/tr
```

and once you have an article you can get the authors with the XPath

```
.//div[@class="gs_gray"][1]
```

using the article as the reference node, so this

```
$content=file_get_contents('https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate');
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach($xp->query('//*[@id="gsc_a_b"]/tr') as $article){
//    var_dump($domd->saveHTML($article));
    foreach($xp->query('.//div[@class="gs_gray"][1]',$article) as $authors){
      var_dump($authors->textContent);

    }
}
```

outputs:

```
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
string(53) "Y Shen, M Voisin, A Aliamiri, A Avati, A Hannun, A Ng"
string(74) "J Irvin, P Rajpurkar, M Ko, Y Yu, S Ciurea-Ilcus, C Chute, H Marklund, ..."
string(70) "D Rolnick, PL Donti, LH Kaack, K Kochanski, A Lacoste, K Sankaran, ..."
string(73) "F Maksimovic, B Wheeler, DC Burnett, O Khan, S Mesri, I Suciu, L Lee, ..."
string(63) "A Park, C Chute, P Rajpurkar, J Lou, RL Ball, K Shpanskaya, ..."
string(48) "J Lee, Z Xie, C Wang, M Drach, D Jurafsky, AY Ng"
string(75) "R Pranav, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, M Domenico, CP Langlotz, ..."
string(73) "MT Chiu, X Xu, K Wang, J Hobbs, N Hovakimyan, TS Huang, H Shi, Y Wei, ..."
string(56) "A Smit, S Jain, P Rajpurkar, A Pareek, AY Ng, MP Lungren"
string(69) "P Rajpurkar, A Park, J Irvin, C Chute, M Bereket, D Mastrodicasa, ..."
string(68) "P Rajpurkar, A Joshi, A Pareek, P Chen, A Kiani, J Irvin, AY Ng, ..."
string(69) "A Kiani, B Uyumazturk, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, R Gao, E Jones, Y Yu, ..."
string(40) "S Zhou, J Zhang, H Jiang, T Lundh, AY Ng"
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G Diamos, E Elsen, ..."
string(63) "A Hannun, C Case, J Casper, B Catanzaro, G DIAMOS, E Elsen, ..."
string(40) "G Yuan, S Yang, S Yang, A Ng, MJ Oursler"
string(77) "G McNicol, E Fluet-chouinard, Z Zhang, J Irvin, S Zhou, F Lu, A Kondrich, ..."
string(69) "B Uyumazturk, A Kiani, P Rajpurkar, A Wang, RL Ball, R Gao, Y Yu, ..."
string(52) "B Wheeler, A Ng, B Kilberg, F Maksimovic, KSJ Pister"
string(50) "T Duan, A Avati, DY Ding, S Basu, AY Ng, A Schuler"
```

(and as an optimization note, if you use curl with CURLOPT_ENCODING, it will be faster than using file_get_contents() - curl supports gzip, file_get_contents() doesn't - also curl supports reading until "Content-Length" and stops reading, while file_get_contents() will just read until the remote server close the socket, which on some websites makes file_get_contents() significantly slower than curl.)

Comment: Thanks! One more issue, this process doesn't work all the time. Sometimes it gives 'HTTP ERROR 500'. Does google blocks such automated scrapping?

Comment: @mnur do you mean your code gets a 500 response from google, or do you mean that you get a 500 error from your own webserver when you try to run the code? if it's the latter then check your php error log, but if the 500 is from google, i guess google has a bug somewhere and you should just try again, 500 isn't used for rate limiting, it's used for when when bugs/server-errors crash the website.

Comment: I have tried several times that time, I was getting the same error. But today again I have tried and got the expected output. As I am doing this scrapping operation for thousands of url, hence I think google is blocking while making excessive request at same time from an IP address. I need to find a trick to give pause after every request. Can you help me on that?

Comment: @mnur could just use the sleep() command after fetching a page - or if that's too slow for you, you can use proxies/multiple IPs to do your call. i can help with that if you got a budget, contact info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile)